# Dynamically check a radiobutton using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a div which has an input for creating the radio button dynamically I need to check one value by default. I used a unique name for all radio buttons and selected them using document.querySelector with a combination of name and value

Answer (score 1):

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) will help you.

**Logic**

- Render the radio buttons with available option.
- On change of the dropdown update the `checked` property of the radio buttons, by selecting them using correct attribute.

I used a unique name for all radio buttons and selected them using `document.querySelector` with a combination of `name` and `value`

**Working Fiddle**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  const genders = ['Male', 'Female', 'None'];
  let template = '';
  genders.forEach((gender) => {
    template += `
      <div>
        <input id="${gender}_Gender" 
          class="htmlControl"
          type="radio" 
            ${gender === "None" ? 'checked' : ''}
            name = "gender_selection_radio" 
            value="${gender}">
            <label for="${gender}_Gender_${gender}" class="form_label"> ${gender}</label>
      </div>`
  });
  $("#ddContainer").html(template);
});
function updateRadioSelection() {
  const selectedValue = document.getElementById("genderSelector").value;
  if (selectedValue) {
    document.querySelector(`input[name='gender_selection_radio'][value=${selectedValue}]`).checked = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ddContainer"></div>
<select name="" id="genderSelector" onchange="updateRadioSelection()">
  <option value="">Please Select</option>
  <option value="Male">Male</option>
  <option value="Female">Female</option>
  <option value="None">None</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please post  a working code snippet with your requirement so that I can look into.

Comment: @testusernewn You cannot choose input simply with `input:radio:first`. Ths will always returns first element only. Istead you can pick them with value like `input:radio:[value='None']`

Comment: Is the value for `None` is always `value="1"`? What is the logic for tis mapping?

Comment: You can make the selected using the text content if the text content will be `None` always

Comment: Please post a working fiddle with correct data. This issue cannot be fixed if you donot provide a working fiddle in the real scenario.

Comment: Try $(ComplaintDivId + ' #divComplaintStatusList input:radio:[value="None"]').prop('checked', true); There is a change in single quotes to doublequotes